# UEFI BIOS won't recognize USB

Tags: boot, usb, bios, uefi, liveusb

I recently tried to install Kali Linux from a live USB. This didn't go too well. I used Rufus to create a live cd on my USB from the Kali Linux ISO. Then I rebooted, and went into BIOS to boot from USB. It didn't show up. I booted into windows, and now I cant look at my flash drive. If I try formatting it with the default windows formatter, it says I'll only have 2.7 gigs on it. This is an 8gb hard drive! Should I try formatting it with Rufus, and trying again, but using the GPT partition? I read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/848053/bios-not-recognizing-usb-in-efi-mode)

but I'm confused about which partition I should use for my BIOS to recognize it so it would work with UEFI. GPT? MBR? Not sure. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use MBR if you have a UEFI bios, you need to make sure, the disk has the EFI drivers on it.

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm not quite sure what you mean by EFI drivers, I'm quite new to this

Comment: In order for a disk to boot in UEFI mode it must contain the drivers to do so.  If it isn't working, that tells me, the those drivers are not on the disk.

Comment: If the flash drive is seen in the Administrative Tools -> Disk MAnagement, delete whatever partition is created on it and first create & format a FAT32 partition all along. Using latest Rufus try selecting GPT Partition Scheme for UEFI as partition scheme option when creating bootable USB from ISO. Keep File System as FAT32 and try again..

Comment: finally fixed it, all I had to do was go into Rufus and create the same thing with a GPT partition. thanks everyone for trying to help

Comment: Extra drivers are not necessary to boot from a flash drive in EFI mode. Drivers may be required by certain boot programs (such as rEFInd) to read non-FAT filesystems, and they're built into other boot loaders (such as the Windows boot loader and GRUB). In other words, drivers are a red herring for Grant's problem. Also, most EFIs will happily boot from either GPT or MBR USB drives; but some do have problems with the latter, so GPT is the safer partition table type.

Comment: To indicate that your question has been resolved, you can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it as the best answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the "check" symbol below the voting controls. You do not need to edit the title of your question to indicate that it is resolved. See also: [Is it OK to add \[Solved\] to the title of a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101)

Comment: @GrantParajuli We don't mark questions with "SOLVED" here to indicate that they have been solved. Instead, post a self-answer to your question and describe in some detail what you did, and accept that answer. That will indicate to the community that the question has been answered.

Comment: Ah ok @MichaelKjörling thank you for telling me, I thought it wouldn't be something like the (SOLVED)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by going into rufus, and then reformatting the drive with an ISO to create a new live USB with **GPT rather than mbr.** This fixed the problem and I can now succesfully boot into Ubuntu.